# How to delete part of a string in actionscript?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, string, mxml

So my string is something like "BlaBlaBlaDDDaaa2aaa345" I want to get rid of its sub string which is "BlaBlaBlaDDD" so the result of operation will be a string "aaa2aaa345" How to perform such thing with actionscript?

Comment: Do you want to remove all non-numeric characters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd just use the [String#replace](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html#replace()) method with a regular expression:

```
var string:String = "BlaBlaBlaDDD12345";
var newString:String = string.replace(/[a-zA-Z]+/, ""); // "12345"
```

That would remove all word characters.  If you're looking for more complex [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html), I'd mess around with the online [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/) regular expression tester.

This would remove all non-digit characters:

```
var newString:String = string.replace(/[^\d]+/, ""); // "12345"
```

If you know the exact string you want to remove, then just do this:

```
var newString:String = string.replace("BlaBlaBlaDDD", "");
```

If you have a list (array) of substrings you want to remove, just loop through them and call the `string.replace` method for each.

Comment: do you know what you want to remove?  Is it always going to be "BlaBlaBlaDDD"?  If you can define a pattern for it, regular expressions should do the trick.  Elaborate more on the patterns you're trying to match to see if I can help you.