# ActionScript 3: Deleting part of changing string

Tags: string, actionscript-3, flash

I understand how to delete part of a string from following this example

[Deleting strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481349/how-to-delete-part-of-a-string-in-actionscript)

But the problem is my string is constantly changing.

str is giving back a value of: 80.30000
this changes depending on the value selected. What I'm trying to is remove all of the characters after the . so it should look like this.

str = 80

the string value is currently stored in str '80.30000'

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings have functions like [indexOf](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#indexOf()). So, in order to get the position of the character `.` you can do the following.

```
var str:String = "80.30000";
var indexOfPoint:int = str.indexOf(".");
if(indexOfPoint >= 0)
{
    //the string contains at least one . character
    str = str.substring(0, indexOfPoint);
    //now str holds only the String "80"
}
```

[Documentation for substring(int,int)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#substring())

Comment: Thanks great suggestion, i've been trying to implement and getting: 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method subString through a reference with static type String.

Comment: Typo on my part, `substring` is all lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer has probably already been given, but if you're using the number for anything mathematical, an alternativel might be to cast the String to a Float, Math.floor() the float (which should give you an integer), then cast it back to a String if required.